# OSX fill popup button with dictionary

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have a dictionary:

```
dynamic var myDict = ["Off": 0, "Low": 220, "High": 550]
```

How do i can fill my popup button with keys by using Bindings ?

I tried use `.keys` attribute, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa bindings are quite Objective-C based, so I doubt that the engine can recognize the (Swift) key path .keys. Further the property `keys` returns array slices rather than a real array. Slices cannot be implicitly bridged to `NSArray`.

Make a readonly property:

```
dynamic var dictKeys : [String] {
    return Array(self.myDict.keys)
}
```

and bind that.